# R beanplot comparison including a vector of zeros

Tags: r, plot, zero

I am hoping to use beanplot to show a visual comparison of 4 increments in a categorical predictor variable as plotted against a response variable. My issue is that one of the increments is a vector full of zeros so understandably the shapiro.test phase of the beanplot routine will not work.

(this is the error I get)

```
Error in shapiro.test(x) : all 'x' values are identical
```

Is there a way I can bypass this and say if there is a vector of zeros then do nothing for that increment and move onto the next so that my plot ends up with 4 increments on the x axis and 3 beanplots only for the increments where the vectors contain values >0?

Many thanks for your help.

All the best,

Bex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing the problem is when the `var` of a category is 0. You could test for this case and set the values for that group to NA. That should work with beanplot. First, some test data

```
dd<-data.frame(
    cat =sample(letters[1:5], 50, replace=T),
    val = runif(50)
)
dd$val[dd$cat=="c"]<-0
```

And now the data fixing and plotting code

```
library(beanplot)

catvar <- with(dd, tapply(val, cat, var))
if(any(catvar==0)) {
    dd$val[dd$cat %in% names(catvar[catvar==0])] <- NA
}

beanplot(val~cat, dd)
```

and that produces a plot such as

[image: bean plot with missing category]

Comment: Thank you MrFlick, that is lovely and simple - I should have thought of that ;)